# asp.net DataList inside Datalist problems with C# interpretation

Tags: c#, asp.net, datalist

I need to use `DataList` inside another `DataList`. It works fine for me, but when I'm trying to do something in code behind with this inside one it just doesn't exist for C#. Here is code:

```
...

<asp:DataList ID="DataListDziennik" runat="server"
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSourcePrzedmioty">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="LabelPrzedmiot" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("przedmiot") %>' />

        ...

            <asp:DataList ID="DataListOceny" runat="server" 
                DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceOceny" 
                RepeatDirection="Horizontal" 
                OnItemCommand="DataListOceny_ItemCommandOceny"
                OnEditCommand="DataListOceny_EditCommandOceny">

                <EditItemTemplate>

                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxOcena" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("lista") %>' />
                    <td><asp:Button ID="ButtonZapisz" CommandName="Update" runat="server" Text="Zapisz" /></td>

                </EditItemTemplate>

                <ItemTemplate>

                    <asp:TextBox Width="20" ID="TextBoxOcena" ReadOnly="true" Text='<%# Eval("lista") %>' runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    <td><asp:Button ID="ButtonEdytuj" CommandName="Edit" runat="server" Text="Edytuj" /></td>

                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:DataList>
        </td>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

When I write this in code behind:

```
        protected void DataListOceny_EditCommand(object source, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        DataListOceny.EditItemIndex = e.Item.ItemIndex;

        DataListOceny.DataBind();
    }
```

...Visual Studio tells me that `DataListOceny does not exist in current content`. I just want to be able edit items on `DataListOceny` after clicking the "edit" button, it can be placed anywhere on website. Do you know any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because DataListOceny is a control inside of another control, you have to make a reference to it by doing something like:

```
DataList DataListOceny = (DataList)e.Item.FindControl("DataListOceny");
```

Once you do that, you can use the DataListOceny variable. Hope this helps.

Comment: It returns System.NullReferenceException.

Comment: I see. I was under the impression that the edit command was being called from the parent DataList. Anywa, try this instead: 'DataList DataList DataListOcney = CType(sender, DataList)'

Comment: CType does not exist, i need to include some library ?

Comment: oh im suing C# not VB thats why there is no CTYpe

Comment: I tried to convert it to C# for you but I forgot that CType is VB. Anyway, I'm glad I was able to help. Please mark this post as answered. Thanks!